# JavaScript Objects get overwritten when using prototyping

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a Pers(on) and an Employee, who is derived from Pers.

```
Pers = function(options){
  this.Name;
  this.ID;
  this.init = function(options){
    this.Name=options.Name;
    this.ID=options.ID;
  }
}

Employee = function(options){
  this.Sal;
  this.init = function(options){
    this.Sal=options.Sal;
    this.__proto__.init(options);
  }
  this.init(options);
}

Employee.prototype=new Pers();
```

Now when i create new objects...

```
var o=new Employee({Name:"Nik",ID:"1",Sal:100});
var p=new Employee({Name:"Tanja",ID:"2",Sal:200});
```

and alert their Name, i will get two times "Tanja".

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't be using `__proto__` anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.__proto__.init(options);
```

will call the `init` method on the prototype with the prototype itself as `this`, causing you to modify the prototype. Try

```
this.__proto__.init.apply(this, [options]);
```

*Edit*

To avoid `__proto__` you can save a reference to the prototype init function before you shadow it:

```
Employee = function(options){
  this.Sal;
  var protoInit = this.init;
  this.init = function(options){
    this.Sal=options.Sal;
    protoInit.apply(this, [options]);
  }
  this.init(options);
}
```

Comment: `call(this, options)` is probably better in this case

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `init` in the wrong scope. Try something like this.

```
function Person(opt) {
    this.name = opt.name;
    this.id = opt.id;
}

function Employee(opt) {
    Person.call(this, opt);
    this.sal = opt.sal;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {});
```

You can now set properties of `Person.prototype` and `Employee.prototype` and they should behave as expected.

This avoids using hacky deprecated properties (`__proto__`) and should be a lot clearer. `Object.create` is used to make an instance using the super-constructor's prototype without actually calling the super-constructor (removing the need for `init` calls). You could include semi-standard property definitions such as `super` and `constructor` while you're doing it, as many libraries' `inherits` implementations do.

Comment: this is not working, when i'm creating new objects:
var o=new Employee({name:"Nik",id:"1",sal:100});
var p=new Employee({name:"Tanja",id:"2",sal:200});

o.name will not be found.
what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: In my haste to re-write without `init`, I made the same mistake you did. Answer edited.